# Getting errors while trying to build istio source on mac

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

I'm a newbie in Istio and I’m trying to build the Istio source locally in mac but somehow when I run "make build" I get the following errors.

```
...
Downloading envoy: https://storage.googleapis.com/istio-build/proxy/envoy-alpha-74393cf764c167b545f32eb895314e624186e5b6.tar.gz to

real    0m5.288s
user    0m0.707s
sys     0m0.685s
cp: cannot create regular file '': No such file or directory
Unexpected failure
make[1]: *** [Makefile.core.mk:230: /work/out/darwin_amd64/istio_is_init] Error 1
...
```

These are the following env variables that I have set.

```
export HUB="docker.io/shriramsharma"
export TAG="shriramsharma"
export GOOS=darwin
export USE_LOCAL_PROXY=1
export BUILD_WITH_CONTAINER=1
```

Is there something I’m missing? any help would be appreciated

Version: I ran `make build` on the master branch of the source. I did not checkout any release version tag.
Docs: I followed the steps in the docs here. https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Preparing-for-Development-Mac

Comment: Which Istio version did you use? Did you use also some tutorial? If yes please attach this info to the question.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak, I the info that you asked for. Thanks

Comment: Did you have right permissions to this file? In which step do you have problem? In this tutorial I didn't see any `make build` command.